# C# Find Closest Time greater than DateTime.Now

Tags: c#, datetime

Im struggling to get my little function to work.

**What I'm trying to do:**

I have an ObservableCollection of parsed DateTimes like

```
{"13:00","14:00,"17:00","22:00","22:00"}
```

and i want the closest time greater than the current DateTime.Now.

**Code:**

```
private DateTime GetNearestTime() {

    var nearestTime= (from x in TimeCollection
                      where x.MyTimeProperty.Ticks > DateTime.Now.Ticks
                      orderby x.MyTimeProperty.Ticks ascending
                      select x).First();
    return nearestTime;
}
```

What I'm getting is 1 value greater than the expected value.

Edit:

values for better understanding

```
var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay // {18:32:35.4378850}
```

DateTime.TimeOfDay values in the collection.

```
[0:] 03:03:00
[0:] 05:03:00
[0:] 13:01:00
[0:] 17:16:00
[0:] 17:16:00
[0:] 23:01:00
```

The Collection is of type:

```
public class TimeData 
{
   public DateTime MyTimeProperty {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: Do you care about the date portion or just the time?  Why are you comparing ticks and not the times (or date/times) directly?

Comment: Just the Time, I thought that Ticks would be the right way.

Comment: Are the DateTimes values in order?

Comment: No they are not necessarily in order.

Comment: What is the value of `DateTime.Now` when you run the code?  And what value(s) are you getting that you don't expect?

Comment: Your code does not compile. What is stored in `TimeCollection`? It is not a `DateTime` type as this has no property `MyTimeProperty` but you return the first occurance as `DateTime` based on your method signature. Provide an [mcve] with defined types instead of making everyone guess as to the type structure.

Comment: This last edit still does not answer what `MyTimeProperty` is and how this can exist on a `DateTime` type (*it can't*).

Comment: It's a simple DateTime Property. And the Code compiles fine at my IDE

Comment: But your *posted code* will not compile. `nearestTime` is then of type `TimeData` and you return it as `DateTime` in your method signature. The compiler will error on that method.

Comment: I'm sorry for writing it wrong, now you now what I'm trying to do

Comment: What time zone are you in?

Comment: My timezone is Europe/Vienna

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't care about the date portion, then `TimeOfDay` is the appropriate property to compare:

```
private DateTime GetNearestTime() 
{
    var now = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
    var nearestTime= (from x in TimeCollection
                      where x.MyTimeProperty.TimeOfDay > now
                      orderby x.MyTimeProperty.TimeOfDay ascending
                      select x).First();
    return nearestTime;
}
```

The [`Ticks`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks(v=vs.110).aspx) property is documented as:

> The value of this property represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001 (0:00:00 UTC on January 1, 0001, in the Gregorian calendar), which represents DateTime.MinValue. It does not include the number of ticks that are attributable to leap seconds.

Comment: Shouldn't you extract DateTime.Now to a variable? Given a large enough collection, Now would differ enough to change the result.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer but I'm getting the same unexpected value.

Comment: @fhl Probably low risk but an easy change.  Good suggestion.

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_ Can you provide what incorrect value you're getting back (and what the value of `DataTime.Now` is)?

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_ Then consider providing [mcve], e.g. the `TimeCollection` valriable initialized with **data** (not strings), what is expecting and what are you getting.

Comment: my collection {....{"21:00", "23:00"} } and now its 20:30 so the expected value would be 21:00 but im getting 23:00 sure i will edit my answer.

Comment: @iNCEPTiON_ -  `and now its 20:30` <= I seriously doubt that, it would almost never be exactly `20:30` on the nose. If your clock says `20:30` it is actually just after `20:30` by some seconds and then some milliseconds. Your parsed time *is* exactly `20:30` which is why that will not come back as the next result once your clock reads `20:30`.

Comment: I was missing something the Answer provided by Stanley works great!